# Display a png picture on form without background of picture's controller

Tags: vb.net, image

I want to put some pictures (in png format) on to a form. what is the controller I can use to show that picture without showing the controller behind the picture.

Comment: Is this a WinForms project? WebForms project? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean to `PictureBox` control with properties `Image = YourImage` and  `BackColor = Transparent`